# classloader in java is a class itself then who will load the classloader class?

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

ClassLoader in Java is a class which is used to load class files in Java.

The java.lang.ClassLoader is an abstract class

here my question is does this java.lang.ClassLoader class is any way related to JVM's classloaders(1. Bootstrap class loader 2. Extensions class loader 3. System class loader)?

or this java.lang.ClassLoader is a separate class which can be used to create a custom classloader?

Class loaders are the part of the Java Runtime Environment that dynamically loads Java classes into the Java virtual machine. It is responsible for locating libraries, reading there content and loading the classes contained within the libraries When JVM is started three class loaders are used

1. Bootstrap class loader
2. Extensions class loader
3. System class loader

Bootstrap class loader loads the core java libraries. It is written in native code. The bootstrap class loader is responsible for loading key java classes like java.lang.Object and other runtime code into memory. The runtime classes are packaged inside jre/lib/rt.jar file.

Extensions class loader loads the code in the extension directories. It is implemented by ExtClassLoader class.

System class loader the code found on the java.class.path which map to the system class path variables. It is implemented by AppClassLoader class. All user classes by default are load by the system class loader.

Java ClassLoader are hierarchical and whenever a request is raised to load a class, it delegates it to its parent and in this way uniqueness is maintained in the runtime environment. If the parent class loader doesn’t find the class then the class loader itself tries to load the class.

*so that means first System class loader will delegate request to Extensions class loader that will delegate request to Bootstrap class loader here it will search for class if not found then  Extensions class loader  will search for class if not found then  System class loader  will search for class if not found then it throws ClassNotFoundException*

**does JVM always starts with System class loader for loading class?**

correct me if i'm wrong any where

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term “System class loader” is a misnomer. As you stated correctly, it’s responsible for loading the classes from locations of the class path, which are the *application* classes.

As of Java 8, both, `AppClassLoader` and `ExtClassLoader`, are subclasses of `java.net.URLClassLoader`, which is a subclass of `java.security.SecureClassLoader`, which is a subclass of `java.lang.ClassLoader`. All of these classes are loaded by the Bootstrap loader, solving the chicken-and-egg problem.

Each runtime class has a *defining class loader*. For those classes defined by the Bootstrap loader during startup, the defining class loader is the Bootstrap loader. When the JVM initialization is completed and an attempt to start an application is made, the Application class loader (aka System class loader) will be queried for the main class. The Application class loader will follow the standard delegation model querying the parent first, likewise does the Extension class loader and whichever class loader will create the class will be the class’ defining class loader.

Now, when resolving a class referenced by another class or when `Class.forName(String)` is invoked, the defining loader of the class containing the reference will be used to resolve the class. So when the Application class loader has loaded your class `myapp.foo.Bar` and it contains a reference to `javax.swing.JButton`, its defining class loader, i.e. the Application class loader, will be queried for that class, follow the delegation model to end up with a `javax.swing.JButton` defined by the Bootstrap loader. So class references within `javax.swing.JButton` are resolved only through the Bootstrap loader, which implies that `javax.swing.JButton` can not contain a reference to your `myapp.foo.Bar` class, as it is not in scope.

*So, the JVM does* not *always starts with “System class loader” for loading a class, but only for resolving class references of classes defined by it (or a child loader) or when being queried explicitly, like when resolving the main class.*

There are 3rd party class loaders not strictly following the parent delegation model, but regardless of how and to which loader they delegate, there will be a defining loader for each class (the one returned by `getClassLoader()`), which will be the one used for resolving references within the class. The JVM ensures that identical symbolic names within one class always resolve to the same runtime class, regardless of how the particular class loader implements lookups.

Note that in Java 9, the Extension class loader has been replaced by the Platform class loader. This class loader may deviate from the simple parent delegation, i.e. it might delegate to the Application class loader for loading application provided modules that supersede a platform provided module. Also, the builtin class loaders are not subclasses of `URLClassLoader` anymore.