# Which class loader is responsible for loading the very first class to be loaded?

Tags: java, jvm, language-lawyer

As per [this JVM specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se13/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3), a class loader for `C` is determined by that of `D` who triggered the loading of `C`:

> The Java Virtual Machine uses one of three procedures to create class
>   or interface `C` denoted by `N`:
>
> - If `N` denotes a nonarray class or an interface, one of the two
>     following methods is used to load and thereby create `C`:
>
>   - **If `D` was defined by the bootstrap class loader,** then the bootstrap
>       class loader initiates loading of `C` (§5.3.1).
>   - **If `D` was defined by a user-defined class loader,** then that same
>       user-defined class loader initiates loading of `C` (§5.3.2).
> - ...

Then, what about the base case? I mean, there would be the very first class to be loaded, and clearly `D` **cannot be defined** in that case.

Comment: That's what the spec refers to as *bootstrap class loader*

Comment: @ernest_k I expect so. But, can you pinpoint a specific wording from the specification?

Comment: What is your “base case”? Are you asking about the very first class loaded/created within the JVM (presumably `java.lang.Object`) or about the application class (the one containing the `main` method)?

Comment: @Holger Hmm, I originally meant any cases where `D` cannot be defined. If those two cases fall in the same situation, I'm interested in both.

Comment: Well, these are two entirely different cases. When the JVM initializes itself, it has to initialize the classes `Object`, `String`, `Class`, and `ClassLoader` (and some more) on its own, as the Java side class loading depends on them. Further, these classes have circular dependencies. So it can follow the formal process literally only after those classes are prepared in an implementation specific way. The main class on the other hand, is loaded when everything is ready, using the [system class loader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemClassLoader--).

Comment: See also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47320598/2711488)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's specified in [5.2. Java Virtual Machine Startup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se13/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.2):

> The Java Virtual Machine starts up by creating an initial class or interface using the bootstrap class loader (§5.3.1) or a user-defined class loader (§5.3.2). The Java Virtual Machine then links the initial class or interface, initializes it, and invokes the public static method `void main(String[])`. The invocation of this method drives all further execution. Execution of the Java Virtual Machine instructions constituting the main method may cause linking (and consequently creation) of additional classes and interfaces, as well as invocation of additional methods.
>
> The initial class or interface is specified in an implementation-dependent manner. For example, the initial class or interface could be provided as a command line argument. Alternatively, the implementation of the Java Virtual Machine could itself provide an initial class that sets up a class loader which in turn loads an application. Other choices of the initial class or interface are possible so long as they are consistent with the specification given in the previous paragraph.